# Expectation of an absolute exponential generalized beta 2(EGB2) distributed variable

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

For a bachelor thesis i'm trying to impose a new GARCH model using an non-linear exponentioal GARCH model with an underlying Generalized beta distribution of the second kind(introduced by McDonald(1984)). 
To implement this correctly I need the expectation of the absolute z, E|z|, where z is distributed as follow:

EGB2(z; delta, sigma, p, q) = ( Exp( p(z-delta)/sigma ) ) / ( |sigma|B(p,q)( 1+ exp( (z-delta)/sigma ) )^(p+q) )

Where B(p,q) is the beta function.
(Because this is my first post i wasn't able to post a picture of the distribution. You can find the picture on page 523 of the article of  [Wang et al.](http://web.thu.edu.tw/kaiwang/www/journal/2001_EGB2_JAE.pdf))

I couldn't find anything on the internet, nor using calculus/probability theory books, so I was wondering if there is anyone who could help me out with this one.